# Use super with before_validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
 I have this code in my every model.
 Class people
   def before_validation
    @attributes.each do |key,value|
      self[key] = nil if value.blank?
    end
   end
 end

 Now i want to put my loop in separate module. Like
 Module test
   def before_validation
     @attributes.each do |key,value|
      self[key] = nil if value.blank?
     end
   end
 end

 And i want to call this before_validation this way
 Class people
   include test
   def before_validation
     super
     .....Here is my other logic part..... 
   end
 end

 Are there any way to do it like that in rails??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup multiple methods to be called by the before_validation callback.  So instead of straight up defining the before_validation, you can pass the methods you want to get called before validation.

```
module Test
  def some_test_before_validaiton_method
    # do something
  end
end

class People < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Test
  def people_before_validation_foo
    #do something else
  end
  before_validation :some_test_before_validation_method
  before_validation :people_before_validaiton_foo
end
```

You can read more about callbacks here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: @Iambdabutz can i pass parameters with the functions this way ?

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand your question.  You can also pass a block so you instead do: before_validation {|record| some_test_before_validation_method(some_arg) } if you wanted.

Comment: I have function like 

  def test1(att1,att2)
  end

  def test2
  end

  before_validation :test1(att1,att2),:test2

  is this work ?

Comment: No, since :test1 and :test2 are symbols.  I don't completely remember how the callbacks work, but you might be able to do something like before_validation :test1, att1, att2; before_validation :test2;  Either way you could just do before_validation {|record| test1(att1, att2)}; before_validation {|record| test2};